# How do I do the balloons effect in iOS 10's Messages?

Tags: ios, messages, accessibility

How can I do the new balloons effect, like in the commercial? Can I do it on macOS too or just iOS?

[image: Like the commercial]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XR6JtMIdMuU

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### 1. Write your message (you'll add your effect when you're ready to send) [image: Happy birthday!]

#### 2. Hold down the blue, circular send icon—"Send with effect" options will show

#### 3. Select the "Screen" tab and swipe between your five options. Press the blue icon to confirm and send!  [image: Send with effect much appreciated]

It only plays once, on arrival, and does not replay so enjoy the moment. As of now, the effects can only be sent and played back on iOS. (They'll show as plain iMessages in the macOS app.)

Comment: Headers are intended as just that - headers - not body text within answers.

Comment: It's [fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214427/183032) as long as it's not overdone. Reasonable level 3 headers here help the text not get lost amidst the images—plenty of other stuff to attend to on this site

Comment: Did you read any of the answers on the question you linked? From the most up-voted answer: "Don't use headers at all unless there are at least a few paragraphs between them." The entire question was about a post that _used headers as headers_, not a post that used header formatting for nearly the entirety of it. Setting _all_ text (or in your case, 3/4 of it) as large and bold is just poor formatting. If images are overwhelming the text, reduce the size of the images. In your answer, the real problem is the last two lines are easy to miss because the rest of the text is large and bold.

Comment: I did and I consider the images larger than paragraphs. Anyway, this is off-topic—the point was to help people, which I don't think the smaller text does. Do as you wish